# Politically correct term similar to "red neck"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What's a non-judgmental way to say a person or group of people are "red necks" in the sense they may hold some very conservative or old fashioned beliefs. For example, someone who doesn't believe autism is a real medical condition? I realize any phrase for it may cause offense, but I'm aiming for the least possible.

Comment: Three comments (points): (1) it depends on the country you are talking about, (2) it depends on what side of the fence you (as observer) are sitting, as to what might or might not be hostile, and (3) very sensible people can be conservative and old-fashioned, but know that autism is a medical condition - it is a pretty extreme position, and probably not the best example for your question.

Comment: There is no "non hostile" way to refer to this kind of person because the term in its modern usage is negative and hostile.  Also, your "for example" doesn't relate to "red neck."

Comment: Reactionary, hidebound, inflexible, obstinate, old guard, right-wing, dogmatic, isolationist, puritanical, uptight, philistine.

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer @HotLicks ... much closer than any of the answers so far!

Comment: @GreenAsJade Do some of the words sound politically correct to you? I think you missed the whole point.

Comment: I don't think I missed the point, it's just that subtley conveying the negative connotations of "redneck" is difficult :)   I posted an extra possibility that @HotLicks didn't mention.

Comment: I believe "red necks" refer to a certain region in the US, the so-called "Bible belt" of the US, the Mid-Westerners. Someone will correct me.  I do know that a person from the east coast (Boston, NYC etc.) will not be labelled a "redneck", even if he or she believes autism is an imaginary or invented illness, or that abortion is a legalized form of mass-murder. They'll be called something else, the term *ignorant* would be the most accurate IMO. If someone holds an extreme conservative viewpoint, they are not necessarily "rednecks".

Comment: Some "rednecks"; however, wear the term as a badge of honour, so you wouldn't necessarily be insulting them at all!

Comment: The term _redneck_ (which originated in the U.S. as a pejorative term for a rural white farmer or farm laborer) is a very poor starting point for any meaningful description of what a person thus characterized actually thinks and believes. Are rednecks religious? Are they political? Are they educated? Are they Southern? The answer is, some are and some aren't. If I were trying to construct a category that captured the most regressive political, social, and educational qualities of rural working-class U.S. whites, I might  try "unreconstructed working-class whites." But that is problematic, too.

Comment: @GreenAsJade - My comment merely represents about 5 minutes blindly using the online thesaurus - hardly meriting an "answer".

Comment: Use of the term "redneck" is not limited to the rural South, but carries the connotation of a beer-drinking yokel with a 6th-grade education.  Usually not a farmer (though that's where the "red neck" comes from), but maybe a factory worker or unskilled construction worker.  There was a play named *Cruisin'*, based on redneck culture, that was produced around Chicago ca 1974.

Comment: But that does suggest the term "yokel".  Hardly kinder than "redneck", though.

Comment: "Anti-science" is another adjective.

Comment: Perhaps "unschooled" as you are apparently using it to describe people who have old ideas they have not updated to reflect contemporary knowledge.

Comment: @MετάEd actually that's a good one "non-contemporary beliefs"

Answer (score 3):

Let me offer some suggestions:

> **parochial**: not willing to accept new ideas or methods

([Macmillan English Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/parochial))

> **hidebound**: stubbornly prejudiced, narrow-minded, or inflexible

([AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hidebound))

> **traditionalist**: stubbornly conservative and narrow-minded

([WordNet](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=traditionalist&sub=Search%20WordNet&o2=&o0=1&o8=1&o1=1&o7=&o5=&o9=&o6=&o3=&o4=&h=))

(However, it seems pretty much any term that fits the bill is bound to be somewhat disapproving, even if not derogatory.)

Answer (score 2):

I think that any candidate answer to this question has to carry some hint of the negative aspects of the word "redneck".

**Unsophisticated** might be the least offensive way of putting it.

This ties into some online definitions, such as

Redneck:

> "Unsophisticated rural person from Southeast US"

@hotlicks comment offers other less gentle alternatives.

Comment: Yes, they seem to be on the track for sure.  If you lack refined wordly knowledge, that is a form of being uneducated, and a person lacking taste is likely to have opinions and attitudes that are offensive.

Comment: Well, here we disagree, of course.   Unsophisticated is a word that is both lightly perjorative, and indicative in a mild way of the characteristics of redneck.  That's just the sort of word the OP needs to be politically correct while pointing in the general direction of redneck.   On the other hand, while oldfashioned can be perjorative, the picture it conveys is more like Grandma than Bubba Earl.  Stuffy - even more so.  No-one would describe a person who is a redneck as "stuffy" but they would describe them as unsophisticated.

Comment: I have not contradicted myself.  Nor have i addressed comments about autism.   I did question the suggestion of "stuffy" and "oldfashioned" as "politically correct substitutes for redneck". Because they aren't very suitable, for the reasons I have described.

Comment: Of course saying someone is unsophisticated is potentially offensive.    If there isn't the potential for offense, then you haven't captured the meaning of redneck.  The OP didn't ask for free from offense, they asked for least offence possible and politically correct.  Unsophisticated fits the bill well.

Comment: @Rathony - You're doing a lot of dictionary thumping here, but I don't think you grasp the subtle differences and similarities in connotations between these terms. _Unsophisticated_ needn't be an exact synonym to satisfy the needs of the O.P. (In fact, Wordnik's example usages includes this one: _These cuddly suburban folk are the very people - labelled unsophisticated but self-serving middle classes - that John Reid is here urging...)_ Truth is, _unsophisticated_ nicely overlaps with the connotations of _redneck_ in a way that _old-fashioned_ simply does not.

Comment: (cont.) The way you are arguing so vehemently while being so wrong makes me wonder if you've ever listened to much Jeff Foxworthy, the comedian who popularized this term in the U.S. [Check out his criteria](http://www.countryhumor.com/redneck/mightbe.htm) – people who have unworking cars in the front yard, etc. These people could aptly be described as _unsophisticated_, but to call them _stuffy_ and _old-fashioned_ would be way off the mark.

Comment: @J.R. Unsophisticated sometimes means stupid. If you think stupid is the right answer for the OP's question, post it yourself. He started with the wrong definition and suddenly came up with "stupid". What's your point?

Comment: @Rath - My point is: When you don't know what you're talking about, you should be more quick to learn, and less eager to quibble. Moreover, you're really tipping your hand now. [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/unsophisticated) lists six meanings for _unsophisticated_, two synonyms, four related words, 19 same context words, and 80 reverse dictionary hits. Several of those listed words would make excellent descriptors of a redneck: _rustic, countrified, small-town, unconventional bumpkin_ – yet the word _stupid_ is conspicuously absent. Haven't you professed enough ignorance already?

Comment: @J.R. You are again showing how unsophisticated and biased you are. Visit this [link](http://conservativerefocus.com/blogs/blog5.php/2014/11/13/stupid-americans-us-vice-president-says-middle-class-means-unsophisticated-in-dc-youtube) and see how some American people interpret ***unsophisticated***. Just because some dictionaries you looked up don't show ***unsophisticated*** is synonymous with  ***stupid*** doesn't mean they are not synonymous. I will no longer have any comments with you.

Comment: @Rath - Priceless! You dismiss what Wordnik says out of hand, and then presume to teach an American how his countrymen interpret a word by linking to a two-bit political blog. Nicely played! Anyhow, I stand by my original remarks – not just about how unsophisticated ≠ stupid, but also how you (and the [communities you participate in](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/2756)) would be better off if you spent less time ranting about why you think an answer must be wrong, and more time trying to understand why an answer could have merit. A little open-mindedness can go a long way.

Answer (score 1):

**Traditional** or tradition-minded folks.

**Agrarian** people.

**Bucolic** people.

**Country dwellers**.

**Rustics**.

**Arcadians** (by Wordsworth, a great word, but few would understand it, alas)

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/arcadian?s=t

**Pastorals**.

Comment: *Arcadian*, *bucolic*, and *pastoral* carry connotations of idyllic and innocent country living, as opposed to unsophisticated or uncultured people as the OP seems to be after.

Answer (score 0):

Consider,

***unreconstructed***

> used to describe someone who has strongly held opinions and beliefs that have not changed even though they have been criticized or have become unpopular [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unreconstructed)

***horse-and-buggy***

> :  clinging to outdated attitudes or ideas :  old-fashioned [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/horse%20and%20buggy)

***small-town***

> : limited in outlook or experience; unsophisticated; provincial [AHD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/small-town)

Comment: Do you mean someone who lives in the South and believes he should be allowed to own slaves, or at least be able to rent a few on an as-needed basis?

Answer (score 0):

Growing up out west I can tell you the correct term is Redneck.  My brother is one and he'd be offended if you called him any of these other terms but he is happy to be called Redneck.  You can also call him a **country boy** and not find a boot in your behind.  Just be prepared for him to call you a city slicker.

Answer (score -1):

It really depends on context, but you could consider using [***stuffy***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stuffy#stuffy__7) which means:

> (Of a person) ***not receptive to new*** or unusual ***ideas***; ***conventional*** and
>   ***narrow-minded***:

[Old-fashioned](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/old%20fashioned) would be better as suggested in the comment:

> adhering to customs of a past era

If you focus on your example for *someone who doesn't believe autism is a real medical condition*, [narrow-minded](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narrow-minded) could work better which means:

> ***not willing to accept opinions***, beliefs, or behaviors that are unusual
>   or ***different from your own***

[Oxford Online Dictionary, Merriam-Webster]

Comment: I can't see how stuffy or old-fashioned get even close to "redneck"?   Red-neck is more than just old-fashioned or traditional.  One dictionary (via google) has "rural white southerner who is politically conservative, racist, and a religious fundamentalist (see fundamentalism). "   "Stuffy and old fashioned" barely touches this.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Do you mean there is no word for that? I agree. How do other answers sound to you? Do they touch that?

Comment: Honestly: I think the OP's question is "wrong".  What I mean is that they asked for a word that means "redneck in the sense of oldfashioned", but redneck doesn't really mean oldfashioned.  Old fashioned is included, but "redneck" refers to a set of negative characteristics in addition.   My grandma is old fashioned, but she is not a redneck.  In Australia, if you said the word "rural" in a certain tone of voice, you would convey the message more politely, but in general I suspect it's hard to be inoffensenive while describing negative characteristics.